# Qual è il significato di "alla stregua di" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La chimera*, di Sebastiano Vassalli, ho letto:

> Lui l’aveva conosciuto prima che salisse sul trono di San Pietro, il cardinale Ippolito Aldobrandini: nel 1590, a Roma; aveva avuto occasione d’incontrarsi ed anche, per sua disgrazia, di scontrarsi, con quell’uomo altezzoso, autoritario, dai modi bruschi e sbrigativi; che considerava i consiglieri milanesi dell’allora Papa Gregorio XIV **alla stregua di** eretici, e non tollerava di sentir parlare di riforma del clero, di rinascita della fede e della Chiesa, di Chiesa santa…

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "alla stregua di" in questo passaggio. Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stregua) ho trovato questa definizione

> col metro, con la misura, col criterio adottato per

ma non mi pare che abbia molto senso nel brano sopra citato. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: potreste spiegarmi cosa significa "alla stregua di" in questo contesto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il Sabatini Coletti forse è più chiaro riguardo all’uso di questa espressione:

***[Stregua](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/stregua.shtml):***

> Maniera, misura, criterio, ***usato quasi solo nella locuzione prep. “alla stregua  di”, allo stesso modo, con lo stesso criterio***
>
> - ti considererò alla stregua degli altri

...che considerava i consiglieri milanesi dell’allora Papa Gregorio XIV ***allo stesso livello di eretici***, (come se fossero eretici).

Answer (score 4):

Il significato è quello dell'ultimo esempio del Treccani:

> al livello, al grado di valore: *mettere, considerare tutti alla stessa stregua*, su uno stesso piano, su un piano di parità.

Nota che il verbo nel testo di Vassalli è proprio *considerare*.